# How do I skip property when saving to MongoDB without using BsonIgnore?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, mongodb

I have a class with a field that I want to skip when saving the object to the MongoDB.

```
public class Person
{
    public string name;
    public string ignorable;  // I don't want this one to be saved to the db
}
```

I know about the `BsonIgnore` attribute, but that also ignores the property when serializing the object to be send to a client javascript application.

I use the official C# driver and call this extension method diretly on the object to serialize to json:

```
MongoDB.Bson.BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An another solution:
You can cast the entity class object to `BsonDocument` and call `remove` method to remove the fields that you don't need.
Most importantly,finnaly you should call `Save` method on `MongoCollection` Object so that only the fields included will be updated.

Comment: I like this one. Clean, simple and requires only a small amount of code that can easily be implemented to work with a custom [NoSave] attribute and a generic Save method.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own serializer & deserializer

```
public class PersonSerialzer : IBsonSerializer
{
        public object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
        {
            ....
        }

        public object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
        {
            ....
        }

        public IBsonSerializationOptions GetDefaultSerializationOptions()
        {
            ....
        }

        public void Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
        {
            var person = (Person)value;
            bsonWriter.WriteStartDocument();

            bsonWriter.WriteString("name", person.name);
            //bsonWriter.WriteString("ignorable", person.ignorable); ignore for serialize

            bsonWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }
```

the `Deserialize` method is simple as `Serialize` method.

then register it by

```
var ser = new PersonSerialzer();
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(Person), ser);
```